# Quicktime Object Embed Without Buffering

Tags: object, quicktime, buffering

I have a site [here][link removed] (IE8 and Google Chrome 5 only).

I was wondering for the Quicktime object if there was a way to not start buffering unless the user clicks the play button?

I hope to insert other movie files in the future and having them all buffer is not reasonable unless there is no way of getting this done.

thank you.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365521/how-to-stop-quicktime-movie-in-web-page-from-auto-loading). It seems like it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method is on quicktime player use edit and beginning point.

set at the beginning and it starts from the begining and buffers as the movie is played.